# Manage multiple workspaces from a single configuration file in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-workspace

I want to create two different workspaces on Terraform Cloud: One for DEV environment, the other for PROD environment.

I am trying to create them hust using a single configuration file. The infrastructure will be the same just in two different Azure subscriptions with different credentials.

Here the code I am trying:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
  
  required_providers {
    #https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.40.0"
    }
  }
  
  cloud {
    organization = "mycompany"
    
    workspaces {
      tags = ["dev", "prod"]
    }
  }
}
```

I am watching the [documentantion](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/cloud/settings#workspaces). It seems like inside the `cloud` -> `workspace` command I just can use either `name` or `tags` attributes. It is required I have at least one of them in my configuration.

Now in my Terraform Cloud account, I have two workspaces: 1 with the tag `prod` and one with the tag `dev`.

I set the envinroment variable:

```
$Env:TF_WORKSPACE="mycompany-infrastructure-dev"
```

And I try to initialize Terraform Cloud:

```
terraform init
```

But I get this error:

> Error: Invalid workspace selection
> Terraform failed to find workspace "mycompany-infrastructure-dev" with the tags specified in your configuration: │ [dev, prod]

How can I create one configuration that I can use with different environment/workspaces?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, I ran the similar code as yours in my environment and received an error shown below: It prompted me to use `terraform login` to generate a token for accessing the organization on `Terraform Cloud`.

***The login was successful, and the browser generated an API token.***

[image]

*Token received and entered.*

***Logged into Terraform cloud as shown:***

[image]

*In* `Terraform Cloud -> Organizations`, *I created a new organization*:

[image]

***Script for creating different workspaces from a single configuration file:***

```bash
cloud {
    organization = "mycompanyone"
    
    workspaces {
      tags = ["dev", "prod"]
      }
      }
```

Taken your script and made a few changes as seen below:

[image]

***Terraform will prompt for basic concerns while initializing, as shown here.***

[image]

*Now run* `terraform init` or `terraform init -upgrade`.

***terraform initialized successfully:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have this issue is that to match a workspace that workspace must have **ALL** the tags you specify.

So instead of having `dev` and `prod` tags have tags that uniquely describe the workspace. E.g. `my-company`, `infrastructure`. Then make sure that you create two workspaces with different names that both have those tags. Then you can target that workspace with the `TF_WORKSPACE` environment variable.